# find path of program (python)

Tags: python, search, directory

so I'm trying to find paths of executable
now my code is checking every directory so it's feeling like not the best option and it may take some time with some searches

```
def findFile(filename):
    newFileName=filename+'.exe'
    for root,dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\"):
        for f in files:
            if newFileName in os.path.join(root,f).lower() and "install" not in  os.path.join(root,f).lower():
                return os.path.join(root,f)
    return None
```

so I'm looking for exe file that not contain word install cause I just want to start programs for now
any suggestions to make it more efficient

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)